# Connected to Tor Network, still not able to browse the web

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows

I have got a peculiar problem. I try to use Tor 5.0 with Windows 7. When I start Tor a Tor circuit is established and the Tor homepage shows up. Yet, I am unable to browse the web, as no webpages seem to load (not even the Tor update page). Disabling my firewall does not help. I am able to run Tor with Tails, so my there seems to be no problem with internet connection or provider.

The Tor log-file seems fine to me:

```
[notice] Tor v0.2.6.10 (git-cab52fe998909e08) running on Windows 7 with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.1p and Zlib 1.2.8.

[notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning

[notice] Read configuration file "C:\Users\alpha\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc-defaults".

[notice] Read configuration file "C:\Users\alpha\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc".

[notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

[notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9151

[notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file C:\Users\alpha\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip.

[notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file C:\Users\alpha\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip6.

[notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting

[notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network

[notice] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.

[notice] Tor 0.2.6.10 (git-cab52fe998909e08) opening log file.

[notice] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.

[notice] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop

[notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit

[notice] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.

[notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done

[notice] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.

[notice] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.

[notice] Owning controller connection has closed -- exiting now.
```

I am totally clueless, how to solve this problem. So, if anyone could give me a hint or point me to where I could find some help, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Ix it Tor or Tor Browser Bundle?

Comment: Sorry that I forgot that. I am trying to use the Tor Browser Bundle.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Anyone can help? windows7 home premium service pack 1 problem with both: - torbrowser-install-5.0.2_en-US
- torbrowser-install-5.5a2_en-US

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall / reinstall Tor
change the DNS addresses
Use Proxy port 9050 & Adress 127.0.0.1

it works for me

This is proper operation report

Advanced Onion Router v0.3.0.20

```
Click "Connect" to connect to the OR network.
These are the proxy settings you can use:
    Address: 127.0.0.1
    Port: 9050
    127.0.0.1:9050
Use "Intercept" to be sure that your proxy settings are always used.

Download locations:
    http://www.te-home.net/?do=work&id=advor
    http://sourceforge.net/projects/advtor/files/
    http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Servers/WEB-Servers/Advanced-TOR.shtml
For feature requests and bug reports use one of the following forums:
    http://www.te-home.net/?do=forum&id=advor
    http://sourceforge.net/p/advtor/discussion/
(no registration required: anonymous posting is allowed)

[22:37:59] [notice] The Tor Directory Consensus has changed how many circuits we must track to detect network failures from 0 to 20.
[22:37:59] [notice] No current certificate known for authority turtles; launching request.
[22:37:59] [notice] No current certificate known for authority urras; launching request.
[22:37:59] [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server.
[22:38:00] [notice] We now have enough directory information to build circuits.
[22:38:00] [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network.
[22:38:00] [notice] No current certificate known for authority turtles; launching request.
[22:38:00] [notice] No current certificate known for authority urras; launching request.
[22:38:00] [warn] Requested exit point '$8224F92848237E5CF55AE5C1860B0D78D153C239' would refuse request. Closing.
[22:38:00] [warn] Making tunnel to dirserver failed.
[22:38:01] [warn] Requested exit point '$489D94333DF66D57FFE34D9D59CC2D97E2CB0053' would refuse request. Closing.
[22:38:01] [warn] Making tunnel to dirserver failed.
[22:38:01] [warn] Requested exit point '$D74ABE34845190E242EC74BA28B8C89B0A480D4B' would refuse request. Closing.
[22:38:01] [warn] Making tunnel to dirserver failed.
[22:38:01] [notice] No current certificate known for authority turtles; launching request.
[22:38:01] [notice] No current certificate known for authority urras; launching request.
[22:38:01] [notice] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop.
[22:38:02] [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit.
[22:38:03] [warn] Got a certificate for turtles that we already have. Maybe they haven't updated it.  Waiting for a while.
[22:38:03] [warn] Got a certificate for urras that we already have. Maybe they haven't updated it.  Waiting for a while.
[22:38:03] [notice] Strange value for circuit build time: -330970msec. Assuming clock jump. Purpose 5 (General-purpose client)
[22:38:03] [notice] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
[22:38:03] [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Connected to the OR network..
```